# Azure data factory copy activity taking too long to load XML file

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

We have an incoming XML file in azure file storage path everyday, and we are loading them into Azure SQL database using ADF Copy activity. The source is a XML dataset referring to the XML file and the sink is a table in database. The copy activity completes in less than 3 minutes if the file is around 500mb. But when we tried a 680mb file, it ran nearly 5hours. We are not able to find what is the reason behind this huge increase in time. We tried to change the DIU & parallelism settings, but didn't help.

- Any idea why such huge increase in loading time?
- Does ADF XML copy activity has file size limit?
- Is there any way to reduce the processing time, apart from rewriting the logic in an azure function?

Any help or suggestion is appreciated! Thanks

Comment: It seems to copy a single large xml file to Azure SQL every day?

Comment: Yes. around 700mb. As per ADF standards, not sure if this is large

Comment: How about run copy activity in the foreach activiy? It will use Multithreaded copy by default.

Comment: @joseph : It is one big file. not multiple files